# I'm getting an array instead of text in php response to an ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

### PHP

```
if(!empty($un) && !empty($psw)){
$query=mysqli_query($bd,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE (username='$un' OR email='$un') AND password='$psw'");
$exist=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($exist==1){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username_in']=$un;
    echo("yes");
}else{echo("no");}
```

### jquery

```
$("#sub").click(function(){
    $("#spinner").show();
    $.ajax({
        url:"ajax/checkuser.php",
        data:{'username':$("#usr").val(),'&passw':$("#pass").val()},
        type:"POST",

        success:function(data){
            if(data=="no"){alert(data);
            $("#spinner").hide();
            $("#check").html("verifiez");

            }else{alert(data);}
        },
        error:function(){}
    });

});
```

---

My question is : How to get a specific response from php ? I want the data return to be "yes" or "no" and not an array

[image]

### I found the error

if you read what is in the alert message in the picture carefully, you'll find that I have an undefined value ($bd) because it must be $db (a variable that I used in a file that I included in this php file )

Comment: what is the alert value coming?

Comment: specify your `dataType:'text'` in ajax

Comment: your alert isn't showing an array. it's showing a PHP Notice about an undifened index of an array you are using in the .php file. are you sure the top PHP Block is everything? i don't see the `$_POST` variables which i suspect the notice is coming from

Comment: please write isset($_POST['username'))

Comment: Please show how you got $un and $psw.

Comment: @sradha I wanted to see what Data I'm getting back from php response , so I used alert(data) . I don't know if I ansewred your question ?

Comment: <?php
require_once("../connex.php");

$un=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['username'])));
$psw=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['passw'])));

//tester si username ou email existe


if(!empty($un) && !empty($psw)){
 $query=mysqli_query($bd,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE (username='$un' OR email='$un') AND password='$psw'");
 $exist=mysqli_num_rows($query);
 if($exist==1){
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['username_in']=$un;
  echo("yes");
 }else{echo("no");}
 
}



?>

Comment: @guradio thnx a lot ,  I did , but I got the same problem

Comment: I have edited my post check it.

Comment: @AnasHouari isn't the password data your sending via ajax going in as `&passw` not `passw`. that would explain the undefined index

Comment: @Memor-X first thank you for your time , so what you suggest ? I write just passw instead of &passw ?

Comment: @AnasHouari i would assume so. if you do that your undefined index notice should dissappear

Comment: @AnasHouari what same problem?

Comment: @guardio I'm getting the same data returned by php , so the alert shows the same things (I not sure if it's an array but it looks like it )

Comment: @Memor-X I modified it , but still got the same message in the alert

Comment: can you check it in console instead of alert then add it here @AnasHouari

Comment: @AnasHouari you sure it's the same? same message talking about an undefined index `passw` on line 5 of checkuser.php? might be better to output data to the html page rather than using the alert. since there's html in the notice it's easier to read

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<?php
if(iset($_POST['username')){
//your code above
}else{
?>
here is the other parts of the php file.
<?php } ?>
```

It seems that you are writing that thing **inside** a php file which have other codes. So you need to use the code I wrote above to rid yourself of it. When you use that code, other parts of your php will not be echoed so everything is ok.

Comment: thnx alot for your time , but I didn't understand your solution , please can you be more specific ? thnx again

Comment: @AnasHouari post your **full code** in that php and I will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

```html
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['&passw'])) {
    $query = mysqli_query($bd, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE (username='" . $_POST['username'] . "' OR email='" . $_POST['username'] . "') AND password='" . $_POST['&passw'] . "'");
    $exist = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($exist == 1) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username_in'] = $_POST['username'];
        echo("yes");
    } else {
        echo("no");
    }
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Have a little trouble. There is no `else` so the other parts will still be outputed.

Comment: @sradha thank you again .
 you are saying that "&" is what making the problem ? that's why you incisted on $_POST['&passw'] ?

Comment: @sradha Noo :'( , still can't figure out the problem ; Can it be the data-type ? or something to do with json ??

Comment: Cross check again with my code and show the post data  in console

Comment: @sradha I'm quite a begginer , so it'd be kind if you show me how to show the post data in console .

Comment: @sradha thaaank you a lot , I found the error ! my mistake, It was never easy for you to find cause I didn't give the all code .

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/10-reasons-why-you-should-be-using-firebug--net-5480
Check how to use fire bug and console all that